# Tableau BigQuery connector - SQL dialect

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

In Tableau 10.1, I'm trying to use a view created in BigQuery using Standard SQL, however it seems that the dialect that Tableau uses is the Legacy SQL, as I keep getting the same error:

```
The Google BigQuery service was unable to compile the query.
Cannot reference a SQL view in a Legacy SQL query.
```

As per the documentation, Tableau 10.1 should use be default the Standard SQL:
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_googlebigquery.html

I have even tried to force the dialect by using a custom .tdc file, but it still doesn't work:

```
<connection-customization class='bigquery' enabled='true' version='10.1' >
  <vendor name='bigquery' />
  <driver name='bigquery' />
  <customizations>
    <customization name='connection-dialect' value='simba-sql' />
  </customizations>
</connection-customization>
```

The .tdc is loaded, I can see that in the logs (C:\Users...\Documents\My Tableau Repository\Logs\log.txt):

```
{"ts":"2017-01-10T21:41:20.122","pid":23988,"tid":"581c","sev":"info","req":"-","sess":"-","site":"{F3FB300D-09B3-4C60-94E0-EAF83FA07153}","user":"-","k":"msg","v":"Found TDC 'C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\My Tableau Repository\\Datasources\\bigquery.tdc'."}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I can't find any documentation on supported `connection-dialect` values. Are you sure that `simba-sql` is right? You may just want to contact Tableau support to see what they suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You may enable Standard SQL in BigQuery, as described in the [BigQuery SQL Reference document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), or use [Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql), to fit your Tableau dialect preferences.

Comment: if you are referring to adding the #StandardSQL decorator at the beginning of the query, it doesn't work because it has to be at the very beginning, but Tableau wraps the queries in its own, larger, statement, so BQ doesn't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you can't just add #StandardSQL decorator.

You'll need to update your version of Tableau. I tried on 10.1 and wasn't able to use StandardSQL and then I installed 10.1.17 and I was able to use StandardSQL.

You'll know quite quickly whether the version of Tableau you installed supports StandardSQL because there is a 'Use Legacy SQL' checkbox, which of course you want unchecked.